# How to root a Huawei in 2020

Tags: huawei

The question is just the title XD.

I have an Huawei mediapad t5 10 and is still using the f emui 8. Any solution to root it?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223709 no solution if nobody sell you bootloader unlock code

Answer (score 2):

There is no official solution, [this app](https://github.com/SkyEmie/huawei-honor-unlock-bootloader) does a bruteforce to try to find the code, but it requires the imei, and tablets usually don't have that. In issues someone said it didn't work with mediapads.

Comment: Mhmgmhmmh. I will try. Thanks a lot!